# How to program a CAN-BUS arduino shield to control car windows?

Tags: arduino, voice-recognition, can-bus

My project is to control car windows using voice recognition. I have successfully controlled some LED's using the EasyVR arduino shield using and arduino MEGA. Now I want to take control of the windows using the CAN-BUS arduino shield.

Because the car that I own doesn't have an OBD-II connector, I am using two arduinos with two CAN-BUS arduino shields making one a sender and the other a receiver. Now I don't know how to program the CAN-BUS arduino shield to make a simulation of the car's windows ?

CAN-BUS shield that I am using : https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10039

Arduino mega : https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11061

Comment: Just FYI.  There is a stack dedicated to Arduino http://arduino.stackexchange.com

Comment: It seems that you have cross-posted this question to Arduino.SE.  Please don't cross-post, [StackExchange policy is against cross-posting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu).  For future reference, you can make a flag to the moderators to migrate a question.

Answer (score 1):

1. CAN bus is a communication protocol(like RS485, but more reliable). It does not control anything itself.
2. If windows, headlights or other devices are controlled with I/O and I/O is communicating with CAN bus then you might be able to control windows, headlight etc.
3. CAN bus shield for Arduino has Microchip MCP2515 CAN controller with MCP2551 CAN **transceiver**, so you do not need 2 of them.

With colleague we are working with electric vehicle project and we are able to monitor and control using Arduino and CAN bus shield.

If you want to control windows, i would consider possibility to try this setup:

1. Disconnect windows from button and power.
2. Put 2 relays, to have H-bridge(to move up and down)to control window motor http://www.ebay.com/itm/1pcs-5V-2-Channel-Relay-Module-for-Arduino-PIC-ARM-DSP-AVR-Electronic-/261099571172?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item3ccabf47e4
3. Put some limit switches, to turn of relay when window is closed or fully opened.
4. Control these relays with Arduino.

In my opinion this would be easiest way. And you won't have to go throw CAN bus.

**EDIT**
Also provide some specification of car. If it does not have OBD II socket maybe its not new one, so the windows will be controlled with buttons, i guess.

Answer (score 0):

The CAN shield can be both a receivers and a transmitter, you shouldn't need two of them (unless you are bridging two networks together.

Unfortunately, operating the windows is not something for which there is a standard message.  And indeed the window controllers may actually be on a [LIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_Interconnect_Network) bus (not CAN).  I'm not sure there is a LIN shield, but it's a [relatively simple physical layer](http://www.eetimes.com/document.asp?doc_id=1272421) chip and a UART, so you should be able to rig something up.

Then you will have to reverse engineer the messages...

If you can find out from a workshop manual what the CAN/LIN buses look like, you should be able to find somewhere to tap into the right bus.

Then monitor the bus and operate the window switch to see if a new message appears, or if some particular bits change in a regular message.  There will often be sequence counters and checksums within the messages which you will also have to understand in order to correctly replay the appropriate message.

Comment: Ok so the CAN BUS doesn't have access to the car's windows, what can it control ? can the CAN BUS control the headlights, wipers or the airconditioner for example, and what is the signal which will control it ? Thanks

Comment: It *might* control the windows, it might not.  In any case, there are no *standard* commands to control anything on the car.  There are standard OBD diagnostic commands to interrogate ECUs but the control and sensing mechanisms are different on every platform and at the whim of the vehicle manufacturer, so you'll have to reverse engineer it.  And only on a fairly modern vehicle will things like the aircon, wipers etc be controllable I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows is controlled by the LIN BUS which is a CAN SUB BUS. It is a serial one wire communication. The easiest is to use a lin transciever chip with your Arduino so that you don't bother your self detecting the breaks, just receive in Rx and transmit in tx. You need then to listen to the LIN Bus and detect the ID used when openining the window or closing it, once you detect the ID and the packet data, you can replay it.